# How to make an image hover over another?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I was wondering how I would make an image appear directly over another image when I hover over that image?

Here is the page I'm working on: http://sehunyifan.tumblr.com/biastest I didn't make the original code myself I'm just trying to tweak it and implement stuff.

On those images I want a transparent image with text to show when I hover over them, but I can't figure out how to do it.

CSS:

```
.f1 {
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    -webkit-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    position: relative;
    width: 280px; height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hoverimg {
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    -webkit-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    position: relative;
    width: 280px; height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out
}

.f1:hover .hoverimg 
{
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="f1">
    <img src="IMGURL">
    <div class="hoverimg">
        <img src="HOVERIMGURL">
    </div>
</div>
```

.f1 works just fine but .hoverimg does not and I'm not sure what to do. What I thought to do with replicating the entire .f1 section because I want it to look exactly the same but only appear when I hover seems not to have worked.

I'm not an expert with code I'm just trying to play around and I'm not sure what the next step is.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dodkmrof/

Comment: Kindly post a jsfiddle instead writing full code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dodkmrof/ here you go!

Comment: Your url on `hoverimg` is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure why though? ;;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.f1 {
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    -webkit-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    position: relative;
    width: 280px; height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.f1 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hoverimg {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.f1:hover .hoverimg {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="f1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/280x380/000000/ffffff" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/280x380/ffffff/000000" class="hoverimg" />
</div>
```

Comment: THIS WORKS PERFECTLY! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What about a simpler approach?
Have the image you want to display on hover as the background of a div, and the image you want to hide on mouse over as the content. 
On mouse over you can assign visibiliy: hidden; to the conent, and this the background will be visible, something like
https://jsfiddle.net/4g9m53ws/1/

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/300x300');
}

.container:hover img {
     visibility: hidden;   
}
```